# URL location sent to python via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I'm trying to cobble some code together. There are two different functions I am trying to combine into one.

Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<center>

# first function
<form id="search_box"><input id="search_text" type="text"/></form>
<br/>

<div id="jQuery_send"></div>
<div id="python_response"></div>

<script>
  $('#search_box').submit(function() {
  $('#jQuery_send').text("jQuery sent: " + $('#search_text').val() );

  $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "test2.py",
      data: "stuff_for_python=" + $('#search_text').val(),
      success: function(response)
        {
          $('#python_response').text("Python returned: " + response);
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>

#second function

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="urlLocation()">Click here to get URL of the page</p>

<script>
  function urlLocation()
    {
      var loc = location.href;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=loc;
    }
</script>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The Python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
jquery_input = form.getvalue("stuff_for_python", "nothing sent")

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print jquery_input
```

For function 1, whatever is typed into the search box is sent through jQuery/AJAX to a python script, and echoed by both jQuery and python underneath the box.

Function2 uses a button that, when clicked, uses JavaScript to print the current URL below it.

What I'm trying to figure out is, is there a way to click a button, and then get the current URL (function 2) to be echoed in a similar way by both jQuery and python (function 1)? I'm new at programming, and trying to figure out how all the pieces fit together. I realize that the above code doesn't do much by itself, but it could be useful if customized in future projects.

Python 2.7.6, along with Apache2 are being used in my test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand what you are asking.

First, as a general recommendation, instead of using the inline `onclick` attribute, it is recommended to separate your HTML and JavaScript. To trigger an onclick event for a button, you can use:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function_name;
```

Alternatively, you can use jQuery:

```
$("#foo").click(function_name);
```

You can even declare your function inline and do:

```
$("#foo").click(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    $("#demo").text(loc);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "...",
        data: {
            stuff_for_python: loc
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // do something with response
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the answer slightly to get what I was after. In the end, this was the code that got I used:

```
<script>
  $("button").click(function(){
  var loc = window.location.href;
  $.post("...", 
  {stuff_for_python: loc},

  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
</script>
```

I choose to have an alert rather than having the URL be rendered on the page for simplicity's sake. It was the action of clicking on a button (which would create as a variable the current URL), and then having that variable be sent to python that I was most interested in accomplishing.